# CPU Bottlenecking GTX 560?

Tags: graphics-card, cpu

I recently purchased a GTX 560 graphics card, but I feel that it's not performing like it should be based on some tests I've run.  I'm wondering if the CPU is the bottleneck; I'm running an AMD Phenom II X2 545 Callisto 3.0GHz dual-core.  But I'm also using DDR2 RAM, so I'm not sure if I should upgrade my CPU or get a new mobo and DDR3 RAM.

Any input?  I'm sorry if that's not enough to go on, I can add more specs when I get home.

EDIT: I mostly use the computer for gaming, but I also use it for writing music\sound editing.  Also my mobo is the Abit ax78

Comment: RAM performance only makes a marginal difference. Upgrading the CPU is probably the way to go.

Comment: Could also be the board.. What's the motherboard make/model? keep in mind pcie 8x and 16x slots are physically the same size and the card will still run in an 8x slot it would just be slower. The bus could also be over saturated, but we would need to know what other hw you have. With no other info I would say your problem is with the motherboard/processor it's highly unlikely upgrading your RAM will make any difference.

Comment: thanks for the replies.  The mobo is the Abit ax78, this guy: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813127046